# How to create two themes for use on the atlas feature

Tags: qgis, atlas, atlas-generator

Recently I've discovered the beauty of the atlas feature. However, I need to include an overview page. I've seen many things online regarding including an inset map (or index map) within or just above the legend. However, due to the detail required on the overview page, this would not work for me.

There are two ways around this that I've thought of, so I essentially have two questions:

1. The title: Is there a way to include the Inset/Index map as its own page? I.e. Page 1 would have a different theme to the rest of the pages (which all have the same theme).
2. How to limit the first page to be printed once? It would give the same output as the previous Q but I see no way for this to happen. This way I would be able to manually include the Overview page and then another map below which the atlas feature iterates over.

Answer (score 3):

You can have several pages in a print layout and output some of the pages as atlas, the other ones just one single time.

1. Create two (or more) pages in the layout and set up the atlas. To add  pages to the print layout, click `Menu Layout > Add Pages...`
2. To exclude one (or several) pages from the atlas generation (and thus prin this individual page just once), right click on an empty place of this page and select <kbd>Page Properties</kbd>.
3. In Page Properties, you can define a condition for <kbd>Exclude page from export</kbd>. Click on data driven override (<kbd>ɛ</kbd> icon) and set an expression - e.g. `@atlas_featureid > 1`. In this case, this page (say, the title page) is created just once: for the first atlas feature (@atlas_featureid = 1). For all other atals features, this title page will be left out (excluded from export) and just the other sites are created as atlas pages.

*A detailed demonstration can be [seen in this video](https://youtu.be/URizHieiPow) that shows how to create the atlas in the last screenshot below (in german only - use subtitles and automatic translation to english, offered by youtube in the settings of the video).*

As you see in the screenshot, you can use different settings for page orientation and also different projections for the maps: in the item properties, you can make settings individually for each map item or each page.

[image]

*This example was created from one single print layout: pages 1 to 6 are printed just for the first atlas feature, from page 7 on the atlas is generated for each feature of the coverage layer:*
[image]